# How can I use pull to refresh?

Tags: flutter

This code show the RefreshIndicator when I swipe down but it doesn't refresh

Listview.

Otherwise, when I use the same code (child: RefreshIndicator(key: refreshkey, onRefresh:

some_class) that generate random numbers, works fine.

How can I use to refresh Listview with readMonitor() ?

```
class _MonitorPageState extends State<MonitorPage> {
  String searchString = "";
  Future<List<Monitor>> monitor;
  var refreshkey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    monitor = readMonitor();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          elevation: 5,
          shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 29, 151, 72),
          toolbarHeight: 70, // default is 56,
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 29, 151, 72),
          title: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      text: 'Loja Infinita - Monitoramento',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 22))),
            ),
          )),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: RefreshIndicator(
            key: refreshkey,
            onRefresh: readMonitor,
            child: FutureBuilder<List<Monitor>>(
              future: monitor,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  //
                                  // Resumo
                                  //

                                  (snapshot.data[index].titulo == 'RESUMO')
```

Answer (score 0):

use RefreshIndicator to wrap your widget
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html

this is the example
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-pull-to-refresh-using-refreshindicator-and-cupertinosliverrefreshcontrol

Comment: anggadaz thank you for your help. This I got it, my question is refresh data from API called by readMonitor()